# The hangman game backward #10

Tags: riddle, knowledge, english, language, letters

Hangman game backward #10 - guess what was the question:

fill in "t" - I'm common among human; not quite among animals.
fill in "p" - I'm related to things you dream of: car, money, summer!
fill in "f" - My population tends to increase after the first quarter.
fill in "c" - I'm what the above think they are.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

First answer that fully explained each line will be accepted, enjoy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Though I answered first, @M Oehm had the better answer for the "p" clue...)

The question was:

> _ o o l

fill in "t" - I'm common among human; not quite among animals.

> **Tool**s are ubiquitous among humans, while only a small number of animals utilize them.

fill in "p" - I'm related to things you dream of: car, money, summer!

> <strike>A **pool** is a luxury oft desired.</strike>
>  Car **pool**, **pool**ing money, sitting at the **pool** on a hot summer day (correctly answered by @M Oehm)

fill in "f" - My population tends to increase after the first quarter.

> April 1st, the start of the 2nd quarter of the year, is April **Fool**'s Day.

fill in "c" - I'm what the above think they are.

> They think they're soooo **cool**...

Comment: Thanks for linking to my answer, but think your original answer was okay. (A bit vague, maybe, but my answer to "cool" isn't very precise either.) Anyway, you posted the solution and good explanations first.

Comment: You two's politeness make it hard for me to choose.  As both answers are correct, I'll accept the first comer.  +1 for both!

Comment: MWAHAHA! My politeness plan worked! The day is mine!

Answer (score 6):

The question was ...

> _ o o l

fill in "t" - I'm common among human; not quite among animals.

> Humans make heavy use of tools; animals less so (monkey wrenches and crowbars aside.)

fill in "p" - I'm related to things you dream of: car, money, summer!

> There are car pools, money pools and, of course, swimming pools for summer fun.

fill in "f" - My population tends to increase after the first quarter.

> There are surprisingly many fools on April 1st, that is right after the first quarter of the year.

fill in "c" - I'm what the above think they are.

> Not quite sure how tools, pools and fools think they are cool, but this must be the answer.

Comment: 12 seconds wow... So close